# R - terrible parallelisation performance within a function due to pointless serialization, how to improve?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Once a function environment has some stuff in it, serializing all this stuff (even when it is not needed) adds a big overhead to parallelization. Is there then an effective way to use parallelization within a function? I've tried the future library but I need persistent workers, and would rather stick with base R if feasible. Example:

```
test<-function(){
  clct=parallel::makeCluster(4)

  a=Sys.time()
  parallel::clusterCall(clct,function(x) 1)
  print(Sys.time()-a)

  big <- matrix(rnorm(8000000))

  a=Sys.time()
  parallel::clusterCall(clct,function(x) 1)
  print(Sys.time()-a)

  parallel::stopCluster(clct)
}

test()
```

> Time difference of 0.0009980202 secs
>
> Time difference of 0.8078392 secs

If I simply put the lines calling the cluster in their own function in the global environment, this works fine, but then as soon as I pass anything (in this case, y=4) from the test function environment, it's again broken:

```
f1=function(x,y){
  a=Sys.time()
  parallel::clusterCall(x,function(x) y)
  print(Sys.time()-a)
}

test2<-function(){
  clct=parallel::makeCluster(4)
f1(clct,4)

  big <- matrix(rnorm(8000000))
f1(clct,4)
  parallel::stopCluster(clct)
}

test2()
```

Comment: Is it with the timing? Running only the inside (not the function), the first call to parallel appears slower than when you run the function and the last call to parallel faster. Still the average time is still higher compared to running both calls not as part of a function. I have not noticed this behavior before. I will check some of my other code now... EDIT: Written before the edit of the above post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you create the function `function(x) 1` with environment being the evaluation frame of the `test` call.  If you modify its environment (e.g. set it the same as `test`, which would normally be the global environment), it will be much faster.  For example, on my system your original version gave timings

```
Time difference of 0.003121853 secs
Time difference of 1.489178 secs
```

while this very similar version (identical in this case, but not identical if the function really needed access to local variables in `test`):

```
test<-function(){
  clct=parallel::makeCluster(4)

  a=Sys.time()
  parallel::clusterCall(clct,function(x) 1)
  print(Sys.time()-a)

  big <- matrix(rnorm(8000000))
  f <- function(x) 1
  environment(f) <- environment(test)
  a=Sys.time()
  parallel::clusterCall(clct,f)
  print(Sys.time()-a)

  parallel::stopCluster(clct)
}

test()
```

produces these timings:

```
Time difference of 0.003677845 secs
Time difference of 0.0007309914 secs
```

If you had wanted access to some (but not all) local variables in `test`, it would have been harder, and would end up slower.  For instance, in this version `f(x)` returns `a` instead of `1`:

```
test<-function(){
  clct=parallel::makeCluster(4)

  a=Sys.time()
  parallel::clusterCall(clct,function(x) 1)
  print(Sys.time()-a)

  big <- matrix(rnorm(8000000))

  a=Sys.time()
  f <- function(x) a
  env <- new.env(parent = environment(test))
  env$a <- a
  environment(f) <- env
  parallel::clusterCall(clct,f)
  a <- env$a  # Just in case f modified it
  print(Sys.time()-a)

  parallel::stopCluster(clct)
}

test()
```

Here I get

```
Time difference of 0.003219843 secs
Time difference of 0.001209021 secs
```

Comment: Thanks, a little awkward but quite manageable. However, although this resolves the posted example, it didn't fix the problem in my real, large and complex code. For future readers who end up here -- this 'seems' to be a bug in R (3.6.1 at present), such that creating the 'normally' created f function, even with environment fix, results in a random number of pauses, up to N cores. Creating the function interactively -- via browser() then copy paste -- or using eval(parse(text='f <- function() a')) , avoids the pauses. Craziness.

Comment: I suspect your real function uses an object that references the evaluation frame, e.g. a formula or another local function or something.  If you do that, my trick won't help.  Generally speaking non-reproducible things that look like bugs are more often misunderstandings of the details.

Comment: I'm sympathetic to that view, and would love to hear an explanation as to why eval-parsing my function into existence (or copy paste entering interactively in browser() ) , should change / improve the behaviour.

Comment: @Charlie, I can hardly imagine anyone here could do that without seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected. You have a trivial function that takes very little time to process. Communication for doing things in parallel takes its toll, though. Give an example with a non-trivial function and we can talk.

Comment: This communication cost is highly relevant for the application I am interested in, which is parallel optimization, where hundreds or thousands of repeated calls to a relatively quick function are necessary, and it would be very beneficial to reduce the time taken for each call. Communication of course takes a toll, but this is totally spurious communication -- the big matrix is not needed.

Comment: If you wrap the `f1(x, y)` function in a loop, for example, the timings are consistent. So the overhead is the same. Like Charlie says it's the inconsequential creation of `big` that affects the delay of the communication? That is indeed strange.

Comment: @edsandorf:  Realizing that an accessible variable is inconsequential requires optimizations that R doesn't do.  Since `big` is accessible to the function being passed in `clusterCall`, R makes it available, even though that function never actually accesses it.

Comment: It is rather confusing having different behaviour inside a function though. Given that clusterExport works just fine, I would rather nothing was automatically exported, just like when you run from outside a function.