# Parallelisation within a function in R -- avoiding automatic export of objects to cluster

Tags: r, parallel-processing, environment

In R, I want to be able to create psock clusters using the parallel package, and avoid the (I think very badly designed) behaviour where all the objects in the function are automatically exported to the cluster (when running from the globalenv, no objects are exported). I was hoping to be able to do this by evaluating from the globalenv, but as you'll see in testfunc2() , this does not work. 
I want to do this to avoid unnecessary serialization overhead in my functions. In this test function the time taken is negligible, I have applications where it is not negligible.

I've asked a related question before here: [R - terrible parallelisation performance within a function due to pointless serialization, how to improve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59117206/r-terrible-parallelisation-performance-within-a-function-due-to-pointless-seri)
and the weird hack I posted in the comments was sufficient for that problem, but I still think / hope what I am asking now 'should' be possible.

```
library(parallel)

#all works as expected in the global environment
bob <- 4
cl=makeCluster(2,type='PSOCK')
clusterCall(cl,function(x) bob) #error initially
clusterExport(cl,'bob')
clusterCall(cl,function(x) bob) #but fine after explicitly sending bob to cl
stopCluster(cl)
rm(bob)

#inside a function, parallelisation is madness
testfunc <- function(){
  bob <- 4
  cl=makeCluster(2,type='PSOCK')
  x <- clusterCall(cl,function(x) bob) #I want this to generate: Error: object 'bob' not found
  stopCluster(cl)
  return(x)
}

testfunc()

#tried evaluating in globalenv, setting cluster to globalenv, passing text string...
testfunc2 <- function(){
  bob <- 4
  cl=eval(makeCluster(2,type='PSOCK'),envir = globalenv())
  environment(cl) <- globalenv()
  x <- eval(clusterCall(cl,function(x) eval(parse(text='bob'))),envir = globalenv())
  stopCluster(cl)
  return(x)
}

testfunc2()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a different variant of what I was trying above worked:

```
testfunc3 <- function(doexport=FALSE){
  bob <- 4
  jane <- 7
  cl=makeCluster(2,type='PSOCK')
  if(doexport) clusterExport(cl,'bob',envir = environment())
  x <- clusterCall(cl,function(x) eval(parse(text='bob'),envir=globalenv()))
  x <- clusterCall(cl,function(x) eval(parse(text='jane'),envir=globalenv()))
  stopCluster(cl)
  return(x)
}

testfunc3()
testfunc3(TRUE) #now only errors on jane, which is not exported
```